# Problem with hyperref and LLNCS style with both envcountsame and envcountsect options

Tags: hyperref, lncs

I am using the latest llncs Document Class: llncs 2014/03/31 v2.19 
and hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountsect]{llncs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

The hyperlink to Definition~\ref{def:2} and Definition~\ref{def:3}
points to Definition~\ref{def:1} instead.

\section{First Section}
\begin{definition} \label{def:1}  
First definition
\end{definition}

\vfill
\pagebreak

\section{Second Section}
\begin{definition} \label{def:2}
Second definition
\end{definition}

\vfill
\pagebreak

\section{Third Section}
\begin{definition} \label{def:3}
Third definition
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

When compiling with pdflatex, I get the following warnings:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the
 same identifier (name{definition.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.22 \begin{definition}
                        \label{def:2} [2]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{definition.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored <to be read again>
                   \relax
l.30 \begin{definition}
                        \label{def:3} [3] (./llncsproblem.aux)
```

and the .aux file reads like this:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}First Section}{1}{section.0.1}}
\newlabel{def:1}{{1.1}{1}{First Section}{definition.1}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Second Section}{2}{section.0.2}}
\newlabel{def:2}{{2.1}{2}{Second Section}{definition.1}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Third Section}{3}{section.0.3}}
\newlabel{def:3}{{3.1}{3}{Third Section}{definition.1}{}}
```

which results in wrong hyperlinks. Using only one of the two llncs options envcountsame, envcountsect works fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem seems to be that when both are used at the same time, the class neglects to include the section number in the hyperlink anchor, so the labels are not unique any more. Interestingly, the `theorem` environment does not seem to be affected.

Comment: Indeed, I can confirm that the `theorem` environment is not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked Frank Holzwarth from Springer and he answered that he managed to solve this problem with the latest release 2.20 (24 June 2015) of the llncs.cls file. Until the file is officially available from the official springer site, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/cschaffner/d2fa0d260f7074d9dc0b/raw/beadfd4ac110b482f6d755cfd075d34148360e3d/llncs.cls).

Answer (score 1):

With LLNCS v.2.20, the links work but the warnings are still here.
It seems that it is due to the fact that LLNCS call `\newaliascnt` before `hyperref` is loaded.

One solution to get rid of the warnings seem to add at the end of the preamble:
`\def\theHdefinition{\theHtheorem}`

Comment: Can confirm the solution, also using llncs v2.20. In my case the issue was with lemma, so I added `\def\theHlemma{\theHlemma}` at the end of the preambule. But the bug is quite funny, if you start the section with an actual theorem, the labelling is working fine!